# SSIS- sqlcmd from variable and varying number of fields returned by source

Tags: parameters, ssis

**SSIS - Support of Multiple versions of our product**

Our Enterprise Data warehouse consolidates data from multiple data sources. We have a requirement that we should be able to support data collection from different version of these data sources at the same time.

Ex. Customer has three different versions of our product installed 7.3, 7.3.1 and 7.3.2. The data warehouse would in this case would be on version 7.3.2, but should be able to collect data from prior versions of the data sources.

We use stored procedures to collect data from sources into our staging area and then we transform and load it on to the warehouse. The design of SSIS packages are that, there is one main package that executes packages for each table that we collect data from the source. The main package is invoked per source that we need to collect data from, if there are three sources at run time there will be three instances of the main package running. These packages run on the warehouse machine to pull the data from the source system.

We would like to maintain one version of these packages on the warehouse and support collecting data from different source versions.

Challenges

- The signature of stored procedures on the source system has changed between versions
- There are some additional fields returned by these stored procedures in the newer release

Example

> 7.3 version signature : [dbo].[PDW_GetMediaAgentSummary](@LastVersionID AS BIGINT,
> @InitializeDays as INT = 60, @NextVersionID AS BIGINT OUTPUT)
>
> 7.3 Sp1 version signature:  [dbo].[PDW_GetMediaAgentSummary](@LastVersionID AS BIGINT,
> @DataStartDate AS DateTime2(3), @NextVersionID AS BIGINT OUTPUT)

Also, let us say in 7.3 this stored procedure returned 8 fields and 7.3 sp1 it is returning 10 fields.

The way we are trying to accommodate is to use “SQLCmd from variable” option in the OLE DB source to cover the signature difference, but this option does not allow us to bind parameters to variables to get the output value. The second issue of additional fields (or the lack of additional fields from the 7.3 procedure), we tried to turned off the metadata validation, but we get field not found error at run time when we run the SSIS package against 7.3 version. Looks like the only way we could solve is to duplicate the data flow tasks, based on the source version. Looking for better way to do this, since this could go out of control as the number of releases increases.

Comment: Besides the obvious hindsight comment of "don't change your method signature", I would look at something along the lines of what Nick proposes. Use something, like Biml, to create a metadata driven approach to package development. You're already capturing that `v7.3 is bigint, int, bigint output` and `v7.3 sp1 is bigint, datetime2(3), bigint output` so instead of that rotting in some document no one looks at, operationalize it. Put it into a structure that drives the creation of a package. Your master package determines what version(s) of packages to invoke and you ship 'em all.

Answer (score 0):

Packages are very tightly bound to metadata and any workarounds will just cause headaches. You could do some investigation into BIML which is a way of dynamically creating your packages.

There is no nice way to handle this. Here's one particular ugly suggestion (just to highlight options and point out drawbacks really):

- Maintain a 'works for all versions' staging table in your data warehouse (has all required columns accross all versions)
- Keep seperate dataflows for each version in one package
- Use logic in the package (including perhaps .Net script tasks **bleeergh** or queries against the system catalog) to work out the version and run only the correct dataflow
- Process data from your 'one size fits all' table based on the known version

There are other variations on that.

But I think that would be a nightmare to maintain.

Another option is simply have a correct 'build' per site(?) Have different versions of each package and deploy only the correct ones for the runtime for the site. That's kind of how an application works - you have a full 'build' based on various components. In your case a build is made up of different packages.

Your version variations are defined in one package (though you have many packages per source)

Another piece of the puzzle: You can stop some stored procedure column return issues by using adding this before the call:

`SET FMTONLY OFF;`

In short this says 'dont try and *pre-guess* the returned columns from the stored procedure, just run it and use what is actually returned'

We have used this to fix an issue where a package kept failing at design and runtime because SSIS *thought* the stored procedure was not returning any columns (based on SSIS running a pre `SET FMTONLY ON;`), when in fact the SP *was* returning columns when executed.

Comment: Thanks very much Nick. Let me try some of your suggestions and get back.

Comment: We looked into the above suggestions. BIML seems good but this we may not be able to handle this level of change at this time. SET FMTONLY OFF, is still expecting to define the external and output columns. We also tried "scriptcomponent as source" , inside the script component based on the version we could fill in values, but this is taking twice the time compared to "OleDB source". Any reasons why, OleDB source internally should be doing the same things , walk through the result set and fill the output buffer. We are also trying custom OleDB source component, will it perform better.

Comment: I think by the time you've built enough custom script to allow one package to use different versioned sources, you may as well have built a C# console application. SSIS gets rapidly loses it strengths when you're doing dynamic things like this.I suggest either use one package 'build' per source version which is tightly bound to the metadata - i.e. no dynamic tricks, or build something totally flexible in C# which covers all versions